# Почему консоль ругается на код?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Заметил в консоли ошибку скрипта, в чем проблема?
Вот скрин ошибки:
[image: Скрин консоли]

Скрин самого файла со строками:

### Как видим строка 109 и 95.

[image: Скрин кода со строками]

Вот сам код:

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  list('.recept_shagi ol li')
});

const list = selector => {
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(selector) // достаем все нужные ДОМ узлы

  listItems.forEach((item, index) => { // перебераем каждый елемент и вставляем в него нужный спан с каунтером
    let span = document.createElement('span')
    span.classList.add('counter')
    span.innerHTML = `Шаг ${index + 1} <span class='counter-list'> из ${listItems.length} </span>` // тут текст каунтера
    item.append(span)
  });

  const lastItem = document.querySelectorAll('.recept_shagi ol li')[listItems.length - 1] // последний елемент списка 
  lastItem.lastChild.innerHTML = 'Готово'
}
```

Что не так с ним?

Comment: Что-то не так с селектором или разметкой страницы. По какой-то причине селектор `.recept_shagi ol li` возвращает пустой nodeList.

Comment: Добавьте разметку. Попробовал `<div class="recept_shagi"><ol><li></li></ol></div>`, все работает.

Comment: Скрипт вообще должен работать только при просмотре полной новости, а  в итоге срабатывает по всему сайту. Можно как-то сделать, чтобы код не возвращал пустой nodeList если списки li не созданы или отсутствуют?

Comment: Добавьте после `const listItems = ...`: `if (listItems.length === 0) { return false; }`

Comment: Отлично, ошибка исчезла! Спасибо большое! Добавьте, пожалуйста, как ответ ваше решение, я его отмечу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что listItems возвращает пустой nodeList, так как не находит на странице ни одного элемента с подобным селектором. Требуется сделать проверку, что хотя бы один элемент найден, иначе не выполнять код.

```js
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  list('.recept_shagi ol li')
});

const list = selector => {
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(selector) // достаем все нужные ДОМ узлы

  if (listItems.length === 0) {
    return false;  
  }

  listItems.forEach((item, index) => { // перебераем каждый елемент и вставляем в него нужный спан с каунтером
    let span = document.createElement('span')
    span.classList.add('counter')
    span.innerHTML = `Шаг ${index + 1} <span class='counter-list'> из ${listItems.length} </span>` // тут текст каунтера
    item.append(span)
  });

  const lastItem = document.querySelectorAll('.recept_shagi ol li')[listItems.length - 1] // последний елемент списка 
  lastItem.lastChild.innerHTML = 'Готово'
}
```

```html
<div class="recept_shagi">
  <ol>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```